# Does starting Windows 7 check for updates?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-update, updates, reboot

Does loading Windows 7 automatically check for Windows updates?

I am experiencing trouble with the "Check for updates" feature, which I will explain in a new question if the issue persists, but have noticed that sometimes after I reboot there are new updates available which I can download and install properly.

How does checking for updates work in the absence of using the manual "Check for updates" feature. Is restarting Windows a substitute for using this feature?

Comment: If Windows 7 Update Check is set to Automatic, then it will check for updates upon startup. It may take 5 minutes to get going. If Automatic Updates have been disabled, it will not check automatically but you certainly can do a Manual Check. If updates have not run for some months, use the Microsoft Update Troubleshooting process  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/971058

Comment: "How does checking for updates work in the absence of using the manual "Check for update" Its the same process, one is silent and the other has a user interface. Yes a silent check for updates happens on every boot of windows 7.

Comment: It's important to point out that there are several updates for Windows 7 that are required to received the most current updates.  If you have recently reinstalled Windows 7 Service Pack 1, and are experiencing problems getting updates, the most likely case is your system is missing these required well documented updates.  We have existing questions which outline what these updates, I just don't have a link, to those question at this time.

Comment: Kind of a moot point. In one week you will never have to worry about Windows 7 updates again. They won’t exist.

Comment: @Appleoddity unless you purchase extended support.

Comment: Sometimes if the machine needs a reboot to finish applying an update, it won't get any further updates until it's finished. If it's just not doing it automatically while on, you can force check for updates by using `wuauclt /detectnow` in cmd prompt (other useful commands such as resetting exist too)

Comment: @Appleoddity - Any update already released for Windows 7 will still exist.  Just like updates for Windows XP still exist.

Comment: @user1125262 - back earlier I asked you to use the process in the Microsoft Troubleshooting article. We had used this when we had Windows 7 machines and the steps work well. Please try these steps to correct your issues